# net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, model-driven

I am using Struts 2 class which implements `ModelDriven`. I am able to pass the data from jQuery and save the data on the database.

When I try to retrieve the data back and pass it back to jQuery, I am not sure why it's not available in jQuery. I am sure I am missing something with the basic flow.

**Here is my action class:**

```
public HttpHeaders index() {
    model = projectService.getProjectDetails(project.getUserID());
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("success").setLocationId("");
} 

@Override
public Object getModel() {
    return project;
}

public Project getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}
```

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
function getProjectDetails() {
    var userID = localStorage.getItem('userID');
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : '/SUH/project.json',
        data : {
            userID : userID
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        async : true
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log('element project--->' + index + ":" + element);
            
        });
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('faik');
    });
}
```

The model object in the `Action` class has all the data available but I tried to return model or project objects but both didn't work.

Comment: I tried sending the model object back to the JQuery and I get a JSON error..   Should I format it to JSON and send it net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy$StrictCycleDetectionStrategy.handleRepeatedReferenceAsObject(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:73)
 net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:658)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but how does your ajax call know what function to call in the Action class?

Comment: Its based on the request type. As this is a GET request, it calls the index() method

Comment: `getModel() { return project;}` but `model = ...`

Comment: I tried with both return model or project both giving me the same error. Now I am getting a JSON exception referring to the net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!.     I tried with @JsonBackReference by applying it to the child on parent class but didnt work.. Any help

Comment: @CrazyMac Why are you using `async:true`, it's deprecated.

Comment: @RomanC I will remove it. I was not aware of it.
I added JsonIgnore and jsonbackreference to the child elements and I was able to save the data but when I try to retrieve, I get the same error. I am not sure as I am dealing with the same elements. Any guidance here?

Comment: You don't save any data and these JsonIgnore and jsonbackreference are useless.

Comment: ok I think I didnt provide enough info. I was able to add those annotations and fix it while saving the data but I see the same error while fetching the data as well and not able to figure it out

Comment: If there is *There is a cycle in the hierarchy* then fix it.

Comment: I am not following you, I have a bean which is a parent to couple of others.. I am not sure how it works while pushing/saving the records but not working while fetching it.

Comment: Get your model and try to serialize it to json by yourself, if it fails with *There is a cycle in the hierarchy*, then it is cycle in the hierarchy and you need to get rid of it.

Comment: This is my method in the action.. Do you want me to serialize this model object? How do I check the hierarchy issue ?

Comment: Do you get an exception on serializing model? BTW don't forget to @CrazyMac mention people.

Comment: @AleksandrM Sure.. This is the exception I get
net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!

Comment: @AleksandrM
This is my struts method
 public HttpHeaders index() {
  
  //model = projectService.getProjectDetails(userID);
  model = objProjectDAOImpl.getProjectDetails(userID);
  return new DefaultHttpHeaders("success").setLocationId("");
 }

The object returned to model looks fine with a list of domain object. But when after the return statement I get the error below on hierarchy

net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!

Comment: And your question is? *Looks fine* doesn't mean it is serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Struts2 REST plugin is using [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) for serialization your beans. If you are using `ModelDriven` then it accesses your model directly when it processes a result. Since you are using the extension `.json` in the request URL the content type handler is selected by extension. It should be `JsonLibHandler`.

This handler is using `JSONArray.fromObject(obj)` if `obj` is an array or list or `JSONObject.fromObject(obj)` otherwise to get `JSONObejct` that could be serialized and written to the response.

The `obj` is the value returned by `getModel()`, in your case it will be `project`.

Because `JsonLibHandler` is using default `JsonConfig` you can't exclude properties from the bean to be serialized unless they are `public` fields.

The following features of json-lib could be powered with `JsonConfig`:

> - Cycle detection, there are two default strategies (default throws
>     an exception), you can register your own
> - Skip transient fields when
>     serailizing to JSON (default=don't skip) Skip JAP @Transient annotated
>     methods when serailizing to JSON (default=don't skip)
> - Exclude bean
>     properties and/or map keys when serailizing to JSON
>     (default=['class','metaClass','declaringClass'])
> - Filters provide a
>     finer detail for excluding/including properties when serializing to
>     JSON or transforming back to Java

---

You can find this [code snippets](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html#Exclude_properties) that allows you to exclude some properties.

> ### Exclude properties
>
> ```
> String str = "{'string':'JSON', 'integer': 1, 'double': 2.0, 'boolean': true}";  
> JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();  
> jsonConfig.setExcludes( new String[]{ "double", "boolean" } );  
> JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( str, jsonConfig );  
> assertEquals( "JSON", jsonObject.getString("string") );        
> assertEquals( 1, jsonObject.getInt("integer") );        
> assertFalse( jsonObject.has("double") );     
> assertFalse( jsonObject.has("boolean") );
> ```
>
> ### Exclude properties (with filters)
>
> ```
> String str = "{'string':'JSON', 'integer': 1, 'double': 2.0, 'boolean': true}";  
> JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();  
> jsonConfig.setJsonPropertyFilter( new PropertyFilter(){    
>    public boolean apply( Object source, String name, Object value ) {    
>       if( "double".equals(value) || "boolean".equals(value) ){    
>          return true;    
>       }    
>       return false;    
>    }    
> });    
> JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( str, jsonConfig );  
> assertEquals( "JSON", jsonObject.getString("string") );        
> assertEquals( 1, jsonObject.getInt("integer") );        
> assertFalse( jsonObject.has("double") );     
> assertFalse( jsonObject.has("boolean") );
> ```

But you have an option to use your own `ContentTypeHandler` to override defaults.

The alternative is to use Jackson library to handle request. As described in the docs page: [Use Jackson framework as JSON `ContentTypeHandler`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/rest-plugin.html#RESTPlugin-UseJacksonframeworkasJSONContentTypeHandler).

> The default JSON Content Handler is build on top of the JSON-lib. If
>   you prefer to use the Jackson framework for JSON serialisation, you
>   can configure the `JacksonLibHandler` as Content Handler for your json
>   requests.
>
> First you need to add the jackson dependency to your web application
>   by downloading the jar file and put it under WEB-INF/lib or by adding
>   following xml snippet to your dependencies section in the `pom.xml` when
>   you are using maven as build system.
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
>     <version>1.9.13</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Now you can overwrite the Content Handler with the Jackson Content
>   Handler in the `struts.xml`:
>
> ```
> <bean type="org.apache.struts2.rest.handler.ContentTypeHandler" name="jackson" class="org.apache.struts2.rest.handler.JacksonLibHandler"/>
> <constant name="struts.rest.handlerOverride.json" value="jackson"/>
>
> <!-- Set to false if the json content can be returned for any kind of http method -->
> <constant name="struts.rest.content.restrictToGET" value="false"/> 
>
> <!-- Set encoding to UTF-8, default is ISO-8859-1 -->
> <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
> ```

---

After that you can use `@JsonIgnore` annotation.